# Compare multiple strings to multiple regular expressions C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string array with different names and i have many different regular expressions, i am wondering if there is a way to match all of my strings with one of the expressions so that if one of the strings DOES'NT match then i can call it out? I have this written so far as a method, any help would be great

```
public string[] ValidateNames(List<string> l,List<string> regex, string[] s)
{
    foreach(var item in l)
    {
        for (Pattern rx : regex) if (rx.IsNotMatch(item)) 
        {
            s.Add(r.Match(item).Value);
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

i am just starting to learn c# so i dont know if the (Pattern rx : regex) works.

Comment: wait so does this work? like have you tried running it?

Comment: @aquaballin I have tried running it with no success, i dont necessarily know how to find strings that DONT match the expressions.

Comment: @DylanT you can't even compile that code, much less run it. You *can't* add anything to an array so you'll never get any results back. There's no such `for` statement. Perhaps you should try to write a program that compiles before saying it doesn't match the data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I never said it compiles, i am asking for tips as to how to make this compile since i am not sure how to do this. I am fairly new to coding.

Comment: Start by obtaining the documentation for C# and reading it.  The syntax you want is `foreach(var foo in bar)` which you know, because you wrote it once already! Why did you change to Java syntax halfway through? Writing Java code into C# and hoping for the best might get you some of the way there but it is not a good idea in the long term.  **Coding is an engineering discipline; treat it like one**.  Read the documentation, read tutorials, learn how all the parts work, and then put them together.

Comment: Get into good habits today. Look for small, easy ways to make your code more understandable.  Never call anything `l`; it is hard to tell if that is `l`, `1` or `I`. Call things by what they mean, not by their types. Never use abbrvs. Pluralize things that are logically collections. Your code will be much easier to understand when you rename `l`, `regex`, `s`, `item` and `rx` to `names`, `regularExpressions`, `results`, `name` and `pattern`.

Comment: You cannot `Add` to a string array; string arrays are fixed size.  Also it is a bad practice to both *mutate* a collection and *return* the collection.  Do one or the other but not both.  A `List<string>` can be `Add`ed to. Why did you choose to use a list in two cases and an array in the third?  **This code is really weird; it's like two people wrote it**.

Comment: @EricLippert you got it, thank you for the help!

Comment: The better practice would be to return a new list, not to take a list and mutate it.  So your method should take two lists and return a third, not take three lists.

Comment: Nested loops are the right way to write this code for the beginner. Once you understand the basics then you can start using LINQ.  This code is a one-liner in LINQ; it is something like `public IEnumerable<string> ValidateNames(IEnumerable<string> names, IEnumerable<string> patterns) => from name in names from pattern in patterns where pattern.IsNotMatch(name) select pattern.Match(name).Value;`  Nice and concise, but walk before you run.

Comment: The intention of your program is not clear; is it you want all the names that do not match *every* pattern, or all the names that do not match *any* pattern, or what?

Comment: Right, except it should return `List<string>`, not `string[]`.

Comment: @EricLippert i want the names that do not match any of the patterns

Comment: Then what you should do is write *two* methods.  Write one method that takes a name and a list of patterns, and returns true or false, does the name match the pattern.  Then write a *second* method that takes the names and the patterns, loops over the names, and calls the first method to see if that condition is met or not.

Comment: That is, your first method should be `bool MatchesNone(string name, List<string> patterns)` -- can you implement that?  Then your second method should be `List<string> MatchesNone(List<string> names, List<string> patterns) { var results = new List<string>(); foreach(var name in names) if (MatchesNone(name, patterns)) results.Add(name); return results; }`

Comment: This is a general technique for problem solving that should be emphasized more for beginners. **Break the problem down into smaller problems and write a method for each smaller problem**.  Then combine those methods together into methods that solve larger problems.  **Test the small methods independently** and make sure they do one job very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
public List<string> ValidateNames(List<string> inputList, List<string> patternList)
{
    var missMatchInputList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var input in inputList)
        foreach (var pattern in patternList)
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
            {
                missMatchInputList.Add(input);
                break;
            }

    return missMatchInputList;
}
```